# What's the error in the following proof of the halting problem decidability?

Tags: computability, halting-problem

Let's encode every state and tape word (with position of Turing machine on it) with a single integer. Then the transition function can be represented as a total function from integers to themselves. Now let's apply any known algorithm for searching a cycle in the chain of pointers to that function and we've got it!

P.S. Sorry, it's late night question... The proof has to be complete nonsense :-)

Comment: The problem is that you don't know the cycle length, if exists. The algorithm of finding cycles has already run for 10000 steps. Does it mean that there is no cycle, or that the cycle is of size $\gg 1000$? When do you stop the algorithm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Turing machine may run forever without ever entering any kind of cycle. (Consider the machine which always just moves its head to the right.)

Comment: Yeap. Or, in the other words, the function I talked about would be strictly increasing. Late night question, as I said :-)

Answer (score 0):

The [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) is already given in the form of a total function from the integers to themselves. Both the task to decide whether there exists a cycle different from 1 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1 and the task to decide whether there exists an infinite divergent trajectory are still open.

It is true that if there were a cycle, then a "slow theoretical" algorithm would be able to find it. On the other hand, the absence of a cycle (in general) cannot be verified by any algorithm. But Andrej Bauer is correct, possibility that there are infinite divergent trajectories is what prevents your proof to work in the intended way.